# Decide the Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

If two people collaborate on a work: the (3,3) means if neither of them do any work,
then, they have to be put on detention for 1 hour and then both of them still have to finish the same 2-hour work without any help. (1,1) means if both of them work together,
each of them spends 1 hour.

[image]

I think the Nash Equilibrium is **only (1,1),** because (3,3) is worse than all other choice and of course each of them knows the other will not choose (2,0) or (0,2)

Is it correct?

Comment: Please use minus for the payoffs if you want to say people rank 3<2<1.

Comment: -1 for putting things backwards!

Comment: @sleeve chen: Looking at your other questions, it seems you never accepted an answer. After you ask a question at Math.SE, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Sorry for this since I am not familiar with here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline P1\backslash P2 & \text{ together T } & \text{ let the other L} \\ \hline
\text{together T} & -1,-1 & -2,0 \\ \hline 
\text{let the other L} & 0,-2 & -3,-3\\ \hline\end{array}$$

has two Nash eq: (T,L) and (L,T).

(T,T) and (L,L) are  *not* Nash.

The way to prove some action profile is a Nash equilibrium is to look at best responses. At a Nash equilibrium, **no one wants to change his action if he thinks the other will not change**.

Nash equilibrium outcomes can be very bad (or very good), there is not point in trying to decide whether an outcome is Nash simply because it is bad or good. The idea is that *if the other is playing Nash* then you can not do better by playing something that is not Nash.

Comment: So does it mean person 1 think the other person will choose work together, so I should choose let the other? I am still confused about the last sentence. Thanks!

Comment: Say you think P2 is going to work together. What should you do? If you also work together you spend one hour but if you let P2 do the work, you spend zero hours: As 0 > -2, you chose L in this situation.

Comment: (cont.) Now let's assume P2 thinks your are going to shirk that is, P2 thinks you are going to choose L. If P2 also chooses L then P2 has t work 3 hours! This is worst than 2 hours. So P2 (if he thinks you will not work) better work.

Comment: Finally, you can reverse the roles of the players so P1 choosing T and P2 choosing L is also a Nash.